# Recover Data and tables from .ibd file

Tags: mysql, database-backups, database-restore

My laptop was quickly losing power even while charged, and in a haste to save my work with a MySQL database, i saved the .ibd files and backed them up (Note I am new to working with MySQL, so i did not know of the proper way to do this).

Now, I cannot access that laptop until I get a new battery, and all I have are the .idb files. I have tried looking online how to recover the data, but no method has worked for me.

Notibly, I tried recreating a table, and using

```
ALTER TABLE tbl DISCARD TABLESPACE;
ALTER TABLE tbl IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

To no avail. The error I recived was

```
ERROR 1808 (HY000): Schema mismatch (Clustered index validation failed. 
Because the .cfg file is missing, table definition of the IBD file could be 
different. Or the data file itself is already corrupted.)
```

Comment: The best way to restore MySQL data is using a dump produced by `mysqldump`. The next best way is to copy the data directory over to another machine as well as the associated `my.cnf` but this can be difficult to get right. This is a reminder to have backups of any important data and to have a restore procedure you've *verified works properly*.

Comment: I'm with the same issue...

Comment: @tadman people know that man. They just fucked up because of the crash server cannot restart to extract data out.